# SPARQL Query Execution Time Measurement Command

Tags: sparql, virtuoso

I need to measure SPARQL query execution time. Could you please inform me what command I need to use for that? I am using Virtuoso.

Answer (score 0):

Virtuoso 7 lets you get the compilation (query plan) and query execution time of a query using [the `profile` function](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/databaseadmsrv.html#readingqueryprofile).

You can also enable general query logging and profiling using [the `prof_enable` function](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/databaseadmsrv.html#querylogging).